# Login script for using PHP and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am new to PHP and can't figure out what is wrong with my script. Looked everywhere online but it still isn't working. I have a simple login form:

Email:

Password:

And a sign in button in html.

```
<?php

#starts a new session
session_start();

#includes a database connection
$serverName = "ServerNamehere"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DatabaseNameHere", 
"UID"=>"ServerUsernameHere", "PWD"=>"ServerPasswordHere");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

#catches user/password submitted by html form
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

#checks if the html form is filled
if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
echo "Fill all the fields!";
}else{

#searches for email and password in the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Test] WHERE UserEmail(SQL Table 
column)='{$email}' AND"
     "UserPassword(SQL table column)='{$password}';
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  

#checks if the search was made
if($result === false){
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

#checks if the search brought some row and if it is one only row
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1){
   echo "Email/password not found";
}else{

#creates sessions
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
   $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
   $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
   $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
   $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
}
#redirects user
header("Location: homepage.html");
}
}

?>
```

My html connects to this php file through

```
form class="login-form" name = 'signin.php'>
```

At the moment, when i enter the correct credentials and click sign in nothing happens. Is there anything huge i am missing here that i should check first?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it your form is never posting to the PHP script.
You'll want to change your `form` element, it should be the `action` property that specifies where the form posts to, not `name.` For example:

```
<form class="login-form" action="signin.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a updated code you have a missing " caracter on ...'{$password}'; and two " caracter on ...AND"
     "User...:

```
<?php

#starts a new session
session_start();

#includes a database connection
$serverName = "ServerNamehere"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DatabaseNameHere", 
"UID"=>"ServerUsernameHere", "PWD"=>"ServerPasswordHere");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

#catches user/password submitted by html form
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

#checks if the html form is filled
if(empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
echo "Fill all the fields!";
}else{

#searches for email and password in the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Test] WHERE UserEmail(SQL Table 
column)='{$email}' AND UserPassword(SQL table column)='{$password}'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  

#checks if the search was made
if($result === false){
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

#checks if the search brought some row and if it is one only row
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1){
   echo "Email/password not found";
}else{

#creates sessions
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
   $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
   $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
   $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
   $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
}
#redirects user
header("Location: homepage.html");
}
}

?>
```